# Submit button closes fancy box

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, fancybox

I have a form that I display inside of a fancybox modal. I am using JQuery and AJAX to submit the form. But for some reason, when I hit submit, the fancybox modal closes. The form gets submitted via my JQUERY and AJAX just fine. This is a problem because if there are any errors, they are supposed to be displayed inside of the modal. What can I do to stop it from closing upon submit?

My JQUERY and AJAX:

```
    $("#change-pass").submit(function() {

        var dataString = $(this).serialize();
        var $this = $(this);
        $.ajax({  
            type: "POST",  
            url: "change_password.php",  
            data: dataString,
            success: function(html) {
                $this.parent().find('.tutorial-text').html(html);
            }
        }); 


        return false; 

    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is $this.parent()? Maybe that is the element that contains the fancybox?

Comment: Is `$("#change-pass")` your form's selector?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ajax, you may need another fancybox for the errors. You could add an `error` handler to your ajax call like :

```
$("#change-pass").submit(function() {

    var dataString = $(this).serialize();
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "change_password.php",  
        data: dataString,
        success: function(html) {
            $this.parent().find('.tutorial-text').html(html);
        },
        error : function(html){
            var errorMsg = // build your error msg here
            $.fancybox.open(errorMsg, {
                // API options 
            })
        }
    }); 
    return false;
});
```